# Is there a tool in xcode that allows me to look at the data in my xcdatamodel file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

Is there a GUI tool in xcode that will allow me to preview the data in my xcdatamodel file?

Comment: The xcdatamodel file is actually not a file but a directory. It contains information about your data model. Are you sure that's what you want to look at?

Comment: No I am not sure (lol). I just want to look at the data without having to go into code and write a query to list the rows/records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  There are several SQLite database viewers though.  I prefer MesaSQLite: http://download.cnet.com/MesaSQLite/3000-2065_4-166835.html

Comment: there is an extension for firefox also. Look for SQLite Manager.

Comment: As noted, if you used SQLite as the back-end you can use several tools. I too like the free Firefox plug-in SQLite Manager. In fact, I like it so much I run Firefox exclusively for that purpose, prefering Chrome for browsing.